# Установка драйверов для видео (low GPU capabilities) чего не хватает?

Tags: windows, драйвер, gpu, nvidia

**Windows 7**

---

Была видео GeForce 9600GT Все более-мение работало (ВидеоСтудио Синебенч и т.д.) Подкупил 650Ти, поставил вместо. При загрузке пожаловалось на библиотеки OpenGL. Переставил драйвера - заработало. Но все же нужно было переустановить систему (на другой винчестер)

Переустановил. Вроде и драйверы поставил, но Видеоистудия теперь выдает такое (при попытке применить New BlueTitler):

```
titler can't work due to low gpu capabilities
```

New BlueTitler это один из фильтров. Сама студия работает. НО 3Д титры тоже не хотят (на старой и этой до переустановки работали)

Синебенч выдает что-то типа:

```
Cannot load scheme normal Image
```

и загружается не в привычном чёрном интерфейсе, но в сером (без скинов)

Что-то мне подсказывает, что я не всё поставил. Только вот ума не приложу, что ещё надо?

Comment: в первом сообщении написано что "не может работать из-за низких возможностей gpu" , что такое titler не знаю

Comment: а вообще (это не тайна) умеете дрова по паспорту ставить ?

Comment: 1) New BlueTitler это один из фильтров; 2) Подкупил 650Ти, поставил вместо. При загрузке пожаловалось на библиотеки OpenGL. Переставил драйвера - заработало. 3) До переустановки системы работало, значит возможностей GPU хватает.

Comment: Я же написал, что раньше ставил, и все работало, а тут вдруг... Может кто натолкнёт на мысль: что я упустил.

Comment: прошу прощения, не понял значит я

Answer (score 0):

Как ни странно, помогло банальное обновление системы.

Вот если бы ещё знать, какое имеено обновление нужно было ставить.